# How to slide or scale loop cuts

Tags: modeling, mesh

So there's a question I have regarding loop cuts. I don't really know how to explain it, but I know a tutorial which shows it at 00:50 in the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtO9maU709k&t=78s

It's basically two loop cuts on top of each other, one stays put while the other is able to be scaled up or down etc. But when I try to do it, it doesn't work, it's like Blender tells me that I already have a loop cut there so the other one is not needed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the video you linked they are just doing loopcuts and sliding them up to the existing vertices. When you add a loop cut the vertices that comprise the loop become selected. You can slide them using the mouse. Once in place they remain selected so you can scale them.  Unselected vertices will not be affected by the scaling operation.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. Mine behaves the same way as shown in the tutorial video. Can you share more details?

Answer (score 1):

I had 'Proportional Editing Mode' set to ON, which caused the problem. When I switched it OFF, it all worked as intended.